# Prove that If $x_n$ converges to in distribution $x$, where x is a K*1 random vector, then $x_n$ is Op(1).

Tags: statistics

If $\bf{x}_{N}$ converges in distribution to $x$, where x is a $K \times1$ random vector, then $x_n$ is $O_p(1)$.
Could anyone help me with this statement.

Comment: What is the definition of $x_n$ being $O_p(1)$?

Comment: Thank you! $x_n$ is Op(1) if it is bounded in probability.

Answer (score 0):

True. Given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $M$ such that $P(|X| >M) <\epsilon$ and $\pm M$ are continuity points for $|X|$. By convergence in duistribution of $(|X_n|)$ it follows that $P(|X_n|>M) <\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficently large, say $n >n_0$. For each $n \leq n_0$ there exists $M_n$ such that $P(|X_n|>M_n) <\epsilon$. Now let $M_0$ be the maximum of $M_1,M_2,...,M_{n_0}$ and $M$. Then $P(|X_n| >M_0)<\epsilon$  for all $n$ which means $(X_n)$ is bounded in probability.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helps me.